# glassfish-ejb-jar.xml / ejb-jar.xml RMI undocumented mandatory parameter

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, rmi

I have succesfully configured two Java EE 6 applications to communicate with one another over RMI-IIOP by following the simple notes in [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beanv/index.html). One application calls a remote EJB in the other application to get the current time, and vice versa.

Everything seems to be working, but I am confused by one of the elements of `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml`. Give me a minute to explain. I have two applications, Alpha and Beta. Here is the deployment descriptor of the Beta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
 <enterprise-beans>
   <ejb>
     <ejb-name>BetaLocalSessionBean</ejb-name>
     <ejb-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/alphaSessionBean</ejb-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:alphaServerUrl:11637#java:global/AlphaApplication/AlphaApplication-ejb/AlphaSessionBean</jndi-name>
       </ejb-ref>
   </ejb>
 </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

`BetaLocalSessionBean` is a local Stateless Session Bean that I inject the remote `AlphaSessionBean` to get the time. My confusion is this: why do I get the following exception if I *delete* the `<ejb-name>` element?

```
Warning: DPL8007: Unsupported deployment descriptors element jndi-name value corbaname:iiop:alpha:3700#java:global/AlphaApplication/AlphaApplication-ejb/AlphaSessionBean
Severe: Exception while deploying the app [BetaApplication]
Severe: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.runtime.EjbNode.endElement(EjbNode.java:202)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:481)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
...

Severe: Exception while deploying the app [BetaApplication]
```

Why is the `<ejb-name>` element mandatory? It's not mentioned in the documentation I linked to above. Does it matter which bean name I put there? I have already confirmed that I can inject `AlphaSessionBean` into other beans than `BetaLocalSessionBean`, so what is the significance of this element?

Versions:

- Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Java EE 6.
- Java 1.8.0_45-b15
- NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Documentation:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beanv/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting is only logical as that is the only way the application server will know where to inject the ref, i.e the alphasessionbean.

The name also has to be the name of the EJB bean you created except if you configured the name property on the @Stateless or @Stateful annotation which in this case the  ref will be that name.

Comment: "I think the error you are getting is only logical as that is the only way the application server will know where to inject the ref..." In my answer, I wrote that "I have already confirmed that I can inject AlphaSessionBean into other beans than BetaLocalSessionBean..." In my testing, it seems which bean name I enter there doesn't matter: as long as the bean exists, I will be able to inject AlphaSessionBean  into _any_ bean, not just the named one.